# Python Type-Conversion Errors

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, integer, set

In Python, I am trying to write two functions. First, I am taking in a list as a parameter and returning it as a single integer. Second, I am taking in a list as a parameter and returning it as a set.

When I attempt to run the program using the given test functions, I have run into two errors I cannot solve. (A) I get a type error that says that "strings = [str(integer) for integer in list_to_int]" is not iterable and (B) I have unreferenced variables for an_integer and converted_set. I have tried to rearrange the assert functions and redo the variables but nothing seems to work.

```
def list_to_int(list):
    """
    :param list
    convert list to string
    convert string to int
    :return: set
    """
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in list_to_int]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    an_integer = int(a_string)
    return an_integer

def list_to_set(list):
    """
    :param list:
    comvert to set
    :return: set
    """
    converted_set = set(list_to_set)
    return converted_set

# TEST FUNCTIONS
assert list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1234, 'list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) expected 1234'
print("correct")
assert list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 4321, 'list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) expected 4321'
print("correct")
assert list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) == 3124, 'list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) expected 3124'
print("correct")

assert list_to_set([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1234, 'list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) expected 1234'
print("correct")
assert list_to_set([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 4321, 'list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) expected 4321'
print("correct")
assert list_to_set([3, 1, 2, 4]) == 3124, 'list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) expected 3124'
print("correct")
```

Comment: you are trying  to iterate over a reference to a function rather than the list. Replace `strings = [str(integer) for integer in list_to_int]` with `strings = [str(integer) for integer in list]`.. Also please consider renaming `list`, using reserved keywords as variable names is never a great idea

Answer (score 1):

In both functions, you are mistakenly referencing the function name as the iterator in the list concatenation rather than the  `list` parameter.

In other words, in `list_to_int`, change

```
strings = [str(integer) for integer in list_to_int]
```

to

```
strings = [str(integer) for integer in list]
```

and in `list_to_set` change

```
converted_set = set(list_to_set)
```

to

```
converted_set = set(list)
```

Also, I would recommend against naming function parameters `list`. The name `list` is reserved as the default constructor for list objects, so its best to not overwrite it in that context and name the parameter something else (i.e. `l`, `arr`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `list_to_int`, which is the function itself... you have to iterate over the `list` parameter.
Same thing with the second function; you are trying to convert the actual function to a set instead of the function's parameter.

Re-write your code like this:

```
def list_to_int(list):
    """
    :param list
    convert list to string
    convert string to int
    :return: set
    """
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in list]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    an_integer = int(a_string)
    return an_integer

def list_to_set(list):
    """
    :param list:
    convert to set
    :return: set
    """
    converted_set = set(list)
    return converted_set

# TEST FUNCTIONS
assert list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1234, 'list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) expected 1234'
print("correct")
assert list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 4321, 'list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) expected 4321'
print("correct")
assert list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) == 3124, 'list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) expected 3124'
print("correct")

assert list_to_set([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1234, 'list_to_int([1, 2, 3, 4]) expected 1234'
print("correct")
assert list_to_set([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 4321, 'list_to_int([4, 3, 2, 1]) expected 4321'
print("correct")
assert list_to_set([3, 1, 2, 4]) == 3124, 'list_to_int([3, 1, 2, 4]) expected 3124'
print("correct")
```